# How to reorder a list based on the results of another list?

Tags: python, dictionary, cluster-analysis

I have a list that was sorted into clusters or groups based on their size.

```
l = [4, 55, 8, 9, 12, 11, 11, 813, 832, 774, 781, 5, 769, 22]

clusters = [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]
```

However, the sorting is wrong. There is no way to modify a base function of a package, so I wanted to reorder the clusters so that it renumbers them in an ascending numerical order.

This is the result I want:

```
l = [4, 55, 8, 9, 12, 11, 11, 813, 832, 774, 781, 5, 769, 22]

clusters = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]
```

As you can see, how the items in the list are associated with a unique cluster shouldn't change- just the number associated with the cluster should be reordered by ascending order according to the items in the list. Is there a way I can do this?

Edit: Just to clarify, I am trying to order and put `4, 5, 8, 11, 11, 12, 22` in `cluster 0`, `55` in `cluster 1`, `769, 774, 781` in `cluster 2`, `813, 832` in `cluster 3` unlike how they are in the original cluster list.

Comment: It seems like you have done more than reorder `clusters`. For example, the original has two `1` values and the desired result has only a single `1`. The original has one `3` values while the "reordered" has two. Not really clear what you are going for.

Comment: you should keep all data on one list as tuples.

Comment: is it guaranteed that all members of a cluster are smaller/larger than another? otherwise, ordering needs a more clear definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note, please do NOT override python default keywords like `list` to an object. Also, not sure why you tagged numpy here. I assume your objects are lists.
Here is a simple solution to achieve your exact output:

```
l = [4, 55, 8, 9, 12, 11, 11, 813, 832, 774, 781, 5, 769, 22]
clusters = [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]

#make a dict from clusters to list
x = dict(zip(clusters,l))
#{0: 22, 3: 55, 1: 832, 2: 769}

#sort them by values
y = dict(sorted(x.items(),key=lambda item:item[1]))
#{0: 22, 3: 55, 2: 769, 1: 832}

#remap clusters
clusters = list(map(dict(zip(y,range(len(y)))).get, clusters))
#[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary for such mappings is easier to manipulate. Here is a non-optimised implementation:

```
my_list = [4, 55, 8, 9, 12, 11, 11, 813, 832, 774, 781, 5, 769, 22]
clusters = [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]

cluster_dict = {}
for c, e in zip(clusters, my_list):
    cluster_dict[c] = sorted(cluster_dict.get(c, []) + [e])

print(f"{cluster_dict=}")

# Renumbering clusters
new_clusters = [i for i, (k, v) in enumerate(cluster_dict.items()) for _ in v ]
new_list = [j for i, (k, v) in enumerate(cluster_dict.items()) for j in v ]

print(f"{new_clusters=}")
print(f"{new_list=}")
```

This should print:

```
cluster_dict={0: [4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 11, 12, 22], 3: [55], 1: [813, 832], 2: [769, 774, 781]}
new_clusters=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
new_list=[4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 11, 12, 22, 55, 813, 832, 769, 774, 781]
```